# Java bitwise operation Vs BigInteger

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Is there an advantage of using pure bitwise operations (`& | ^ ~`) over using BigInteger (`BigInteger.and BigInteger.or`) for bitwise operations in terms of performance? memory? anything else?

For i use BigInteger for bitwise operations because the resulting code is much more readble.

example for the code that i will be using:

```
BigInteger bNum1 = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger bNum2 = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger bNum3 = new BigInteger("0");
bNum1 = bNum1.setBit(0);
bNum2 = bNum2.setBit(1);
bNum3 = bNum3.setBit(2);

BigInteger bMask = bNum3.or(bNum1);

System.out.println(bMask.and(bNum1).equals(bMask));
System.out.println(bMask.and(bNum2).equals(bMask));
System.out.println(bMask.and(bNum3).equals(bMask));
System.out.println(bMask.and(bMask).equals(bMask));


int num1 = 1 << 0;
int num2 = 1 << 1;
int num3 = 1 << 2;

int mask = num3 | num1;

System.out.println((mask & num1) == mask);
System.out.println((mask & num2) == mask);
System.out.println((mask & num3) == mask);
System.out.println((mask & mask) == mask);
```

Comment: you don't have to convert to BigInteger?

Comment: no, the operations are between small numbers (max 2^10) for masking purposes

Comment: I mean, the fact you don't have to create a new BigInteger object or two is probably a pretty big performance bonus.

Comment: Please provide us with two snippets of code (including type declarations) that we can compare.

Comment: Very small point: Don't use new BigInteger("0"); use the cached version: BigInteger.ZERO

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is always more efficient to work with primitives both in terms of performance and memory. But BigInteger can work with numbers bigger than int and long. Eg

```
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222");
BigInteger b3 = b1.and(b2);
```

Comment: can you give a use case of bitwise operations on a number bigger than long?

Comment: I think Noam asked for a use case and not how to implement it. Handling subnet masks for IPv6 adresses (128 bits) would be one.